# Obj-C, get the selected row into UIAlertview clickedButtonAtIndex method

Tags: objective-c

I am have an UIAlertView in "UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete" Im trying to get the object in row of the selected cell but I find the way to that.

this is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        confirmBlock = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Attention" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Are you sure you want to block %@ ?", splitRow[1]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
        [confirmBlock show];
    }
```

and when the user click choose one of the option:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
// here, how can I get the objectAtIndex of the selected row ?

}
```

I tried with tagging the alertview but its not work cos the objectAtIndex is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use alertview.message and parse the string to get the number
for parsing maybe try componentsSeparatedByString: with " "(space) and getting the second last index of returned array, which will be your row number in message.

OR you can simply use the

```
 `selectedRow
```

property of tableVIew

EDIT:

But a more feasible way would be to set a object in .h file:

```
NSInteger selectedRow;
```

and set it before showing the alertView... then get this value in the clickedbuttonatindex function